# How to fix this multiprocessing in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to run a model 1000 time and store its statistics in dictionaries. Because the model itself is probably not already making use of the multiprocessing i thought of using the `multiprocessing` package in Python.
This is my code so far:

```py
import multiprocessing

class ensemble_model:
    def __init__(self, df, k) -> None:
        ## do some calculations
        self.r2_list = [...]
        self.rmse_list = [...]    

def worker(components, dic1, dic2):
    result = ensemble_model(
        df,
        k = components
    )
    dic1[components] = result.r2_list
    dic2[components] = result.rmse_list

r2_dic = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
rmse_dic = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()

processes = []
for n_comp in range(1,1001):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(n_comp, r2_dic, rmse_dic))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

The problem is that I get an empty dictionary that instead is supposed to contain a list for each different number of components `n_comp`.
I used ChatGPT and i read the docs to figure out what the problem could be but so far I could't get it.
Does someone know why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: You don't have an active multiprocessing Manager

Comment: **Do you know for certain that `ensemble_model.__init__` comp;letes without raising an exception?** As an aside, you only need to create a single `Manager` instance with `manager = multiprocessing.Manager()` and using `manager` to create both dictionaries. Or do you believe that by having one process for each dictionary will significantly improve performance? 1,000 processes also seems like a lot of processes. How many cores do you have?

Comment: Yes the function works fine, i tried with less iterations (5) without multiprocessing just by using normal dictionaries and appending the result to them in a similar way. 
I have an intel i9 24 cores. What's the correct way to figure out the maximum amount of processes?

Answer (score 1):

Your question about how many processes should be used does not have a straightforward answer.

If you only have 24 cores **and if your worker function *worker* were 100% CPU-bound** then there would be no reason to create more than 24 processes. If you have a mixture of CPU and I/O then perhaps you could up this number a bit or use a combination of multithreading for the I/O and multiprocessing for the purely CPU work. Creating 1000 processes just seems very inefficient regardless. I would also think about not using managed dictionaries, which are very slow.

You should be creating a multiprocessing pool (using the number of cores you have as the pool size seems reasonable). I would then have your worker function return back to the main process key and value information which then updates the dictionaries (or perhaps even better, lists). But there are things that are not clear in your code such as why are the calculations performed by `ensemble_model.__init__` done in a class initializer instead of an ordinary function and where is `df` defined?

Based on the minimal code you posted I am going to make `ensemble_model` a function. If your actual code is more complicated than what was posted and you need a class for your calculation, I am sure you will know how to adapt this to your requirements.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from functools import partial

def ensemble_model(df, k):    
    # do some calculations 
    r2_list = [...]
    rmse_list = [...]
    
    # return key and values
    return k, r2_list, rsme_list

r2_dic = {}
rmse_dic = {}

N_TASKS = 1000
pool_size = cpu_count()
chunk_size = N_TASKS // (4 * pool_size) # Good approximation

with Pool(pool_size) as pool:
    worker = partial(ensemble_model, df)
    for k, r2_list, rsme_list in pool.imap_unordered(
        worker,
        range(1, N_TASKS + 1),
        chunksize=chunk_size
    ):
        r2_dic[k] = r2_list
        rsme_dic[k] = rsme_list
```

But instead of using dictionaries you can use lists:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from functools import partial

def ensemble_model(df, k):
    # do some calculations 
    r2_list = [...]
    rmse_list = [...]
    
    # return key and values
    return k, r2_list, rsme_list

N_TASKS = 1000
r2_list_list = [None] * N_TASKS
rmse_list_list = [None] * N_TASKS

pool_size = cpu_count()
chunk_size = N_TASKS // (4 * pool_size) # Good approximation

with Pool(pool_size) as pool:
    worker = partial(ensemble_model, df)
    for k, r2_list, rsme_list in pool.imap_unordered(
        worker,
        range(1, 1001),
        chunksize=chunk_size
    ):
        # Origin-0 lists:
        r2_list_list[k - 1] = r2_list
        rmse_list_list[k - 1] = rsme_list
```